# Object Rotates slower and only to frame 250 than simple cube with rigid body physics motor

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I am trying to make a simple gear rotate with a certain speed, therefore I added a hinge and motor rigid body constraint. But when I start animation the object only moves very slow and only to a certain point and then stops even before the stop frame.

When I apply the same constrains on a simple cube it does what I want.

I somewhere found that a low scale of the object can have an impact, but scaling up to 1 did not bring any change.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you apply the scale?

Comment: Thanks, did not think of that. I'm pretty new to Blender and simply playing around. Earlier I had found that changing the mass of the mesh did indeed change the situation. So it was definitely a problem with the large scale and mass of the Mesh. Thanks a lot.